# npm is not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm

> $ C:\Users\arghya>npm start
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\arghya\package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -4058
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\arghya\package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! C:\Users\arghya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-04-09T12_50_23_252Z-debug.log

Comment: Seems like npm cannot find your package.json file...

Comment: `npm init`  and `npm i` it says you don't have `package.json` file

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have your project located directly in your user folder, like `C:\Users\arghya`, aren't you?! Make sure you execute the command in the right folder ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Nuxt Js folder. The thing I was doing was, I cerated a project named "Final project" with the nuxt command "npx nuxt-create-app final project". when everything was done, the terminal in mac said "run npm run dev" to start the project. So I did it and it was showing the error.

Nut the thing is the projet was in "final project" folder. So I had to move to the final project folder using  "cd final project" and then when I ran "npm run dev" everything was fine